# How to exclude -sources pattern in bash with space in file name

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to use bash command line to match the file name "`file 9.3.0.zip`".

Here is the test script for explaining the folder structure:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test
touch "/tmp/test/file 9.3.0.zip"
touch "/tmp/test/file 9.3.0-sources.zip"

cd /tmp/test
```

If the folder does not contain any "`-sources.zip`", then I can use "`echo file*.zip`" to match "`file 9.3.0.zip`".

But now it also contains "`-sources.zip`" in it, I have tried the following pattern but still doesn't work:

```
echo file**!(-sources).zip
```

Here is the output:

```
file 9.3.0-sources.zip file 9.3.0.zip
```

How to write the pattern in bash command?

I will use this match only one file pattern in other bash command, for example:

```
unzip file*.zip -d /tmp/other
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `*` in `file*!(-sources).zip` can match something that means the remainder of the filename is not `-sources.zip`.

This seems to work, but I haven't tested it thoroughly:

```
file!(*-sources).zip
```

This also seems to work (but I don't recommend it!):

```
!(!(file*.zip)|file*-sources.zip)
```