# How to get a matched pattern including the previous letters and front side letters until it reaches a specific letter in BASH (AIX)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, aix

For example:

You have this string: `opp\car\G-lion-8648\bro`

I want `G-lion-8648` part from this string but `G` and `8648` are changeable from valuable side or counting side what I mean is that `G` might be `GJ` or `J` and `8648` might be a different number it could be `008324` or `2457476` but the only constant thing is that `-lion-` will remain as it is.

I want a command that could get me this pattern ->`G-lion-8648` which will able for me to get all the previous letters of this `-lion-` until it reaches `\` character and get all the frontside numbers or characters until it reaches `\` character to get the exact pattern.

Please consider that I am working on BASH using AIX operating system and the solution would be preferable if sed or awd are used in the solution because of the limitations in AIX.

[How to exclude -sources pattern in bash with space in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388898/how-to-exclude-sources-pattern-in-bash-with-space-in-file-name)
[Use grep --exclude/--include syntax to not grep through certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/use-grep-exclude-include-syntax-to-not-grep-through-certain-files/221929#221929)
I used some of these links but with no clear answer.

Regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with the limitations of AIX; does it have a recent version of bash (you can check with `bash --version`)?

Comment: Don't worry the issue doesn't depend on versioning .The limitions are related to the options of sed and awd.

Comment: pleae update the question with your versions of `sed` and `awk` (ie, what's the output from `sed --version` and `awk --version`)?

Comment: Is your string store in a file or a variable or coming from a pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pure Bash code shows how to extract the wanted pattern from a variable (`str`) and assign it to another variable (`lion_str`):

```
str='opp\car\G-lion-8648\bro'

lion_rx='^.*[\\]([^\\]+-lion-[0-9]+)\\.*$'

if [[ $str =~ $lion_rx ]]; then
    lion_str=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    printf '%s\n' "$lion_str"
fi
```

- The code prints `G-lion-8648` when run.
- See [mkelement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35924143/4154375) to [How do I use a regex in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35919103/4154375) for an explanation of `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` and `BASH_REMATCH`.
- Built-in regular expression matching was added to Bash in version 3.0 (released in 2004) so the code should work on any Bash that you are likely to find on any non-prehistoric system.

Comment: Thank you so much .It is working perfectly as I requested.

Comment: Note that you could omit `^.*` from the beginning of the pattern, and `.*$` from the end. These make it match the entire string, but that's not necessary here since you only care about the bit in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed you could do as follows

```
$ echo "opp\car\G-lion-8648\bro" | sed -r 's/opp\\car\\([A-Z]+-lion-[0-9]+)\\bro/\1/'
G-lion-8648
```

with the same regexp for your other sample data

```
$ echo "opp\car\GJ-lion-2457476\bro" | sed -r 's/opp\\car\\([A-Z]+-lion-[0-9]+)\\bro/\1/'
GJ-lion-2457476
```